# Open Text File and Split() with exclamation mark as delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, text-files, delimiter

Should be very simple I think, but can't seem to get it to work. Tried two methods for opening a text file (.txt) into excel and splitting by the Other option: "!"

```
Set workbookbk = Workbooks.OpenText(fullfilepath, xlMSDOS, _
xlDelimited, xlDoubleQuote, False, False, False, False, False, True, "!")
```

this syntax is fine but then it says "Compile Error: Expected Function or Variable" what am I missing?!

I also used

```
Set workbk = Workbooks.Open filename:= fullfilepath, Delimiter:= "!"
```

This opens the file ok, but doesn't split the file at all

Help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to skip arguments from a method, then you need explicitly specify which arguments you *are* supplying:

---

***Workbook.OpenText syntax*** (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx))

> *expression*.***OpenText***(***Filename***, ***Origin***, ***StartRow***, ***DataType***, ***TextQualifier***, ***ConsecutiveDelimiter***, ***Tab***, ***Semicolon***, ***Comma***, ***Space***, ***Other***, ***OtherChar***, ***FieldInfo***, ***TextVisualLayout***, ***DecimalSeparator***, ***ThousandsSeparator***, ***TrailingMinusNumbers***, ***Local***)
>
> *expression* A variable that represents a Workbooks object.

---

In your code, you have missed out some arguments, but the compiler will assume you have supplied the arguments in the expected order for that method **unless** you specify *which* arguments you are passing. For example:

```
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fuullfilepath, Origin:=xlMSDOS, DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="!"
```

---

Also, might not be the answer you were hoping for, but I wrote a UDF to accomplish a similar thing without using the `.OpenText()` method a while ago:

```
Function MM_OpenTextFile(vPath As String, delim As String) As Variant

Dim FF As Integer
Dim lineArray As Variant
Dim temp As String
Dim arrayList As Object

Set arrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

FF = FreeFile

Open vPath For Input As #FF
    While Not EOF(FF)
        Line Input #FF, temp
        lineArray = Split(temp, delim)
        arrayList.Add lineArray
        Erase lineArray
    Wend
Close #FF

MM_OpenTextFile = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrayList.ToArray()))

arrayList.Clear

Set arrayList = Nothing

End Function
```

Here's an example of how you would use it:

```
Sub Foo()

Dim ar As Variant '// Must be a Variant to work   

'// Change to a file and delimiter of your choosing...
ar = MM_OpenTextFile("C:\Users\Macro Man\SomeFile.txt", "!")

With Range("A1").Resize(UBound(ar, 1), UBound(ar, 2))
    .NumberFormat = "@" '// Change format to "text"
    .Value = ar '// insert array values
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, that is brilliant, succinct and detailed. Thank you so much, it was driving me mad!